# How many frequencies to display?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, descriptive-statistics

Recently, a friend asked me an interesting question. Although it is not the first time I have been asked the same question. Well, she did some research and presented me with the graph below asking me if she really would have to use all the categories or if she could summarize and leave only the most relevant frequencies (the biggest ones).

I had a big question, because I don't know if there is a test to see which categories are "most representative". For example, in my view, in the graph above, abdomen, hands, nose, buttocks and ears have a much higher frequency than the others, so they must be represented in the graph and the other aggregates like others, for example. I wonder if there is an ideal way (or even a hypothesis test) to select the number of categories. Since this criterion that I mentioned is very subjective. Is there a way to exploit this frequency distribution? For example, if the 5 causes have significant frequencies over the others?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pool the least important categories into one categories called 'other'. Use subject matter expertise and the data to decide which are the least important. There isn't a stats test to do this.

Comment: To better assist, please clarify what the intention is in "using" all (or some) of the categories...¿used for what?  Also, it is unclear what metric you are suggesting for "the most important" options.  My gut instinct is that the real question is something to do with the response options that appear above a given threshold (below which the options can be considered as idiosyncratic and not consensus options).  (This is based on previous work I've done applying voting methods to survey research and latent variables...but before I go on, I would need to know more about the research question.)

Comment: Thanks @JTH! That's what I imagined, because I don't remember having seen a test for that purpose.

Comment: @GreggH, I made some changes to the question. I think it has now become clearer. However, my focus was on frequency distribution (the most present).